# Python .exe Application windows 7 error api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

Guys i have two computer one is core i5 with Windows 10 and other one is Core2Duo with windows 7. My core i5 have python installed in it while my core 2 duo does not have because i build my python applications on my core i5. I created a simple login system software using python (CODE BELOW) and converted into .exe using Pyinstaller. I shifted this software into my core2duo which does not have python installed and my software's .exe file is not working on core2duo. (It is showing me api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll) Error. Now I know that some of you will say that my core2duo may not have Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable but I already have it installed on my both computers and I also installed api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll file manually from internet and copied it in my software directory but it is still me showing me same error.

My Software's Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from csv import DictReader
from csv import DictWriter


win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry('300x200')
win.title('Login/Signup System')
win.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
win.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


# DEFINING ALL FUNCTIONS
def show_page(page):
    page.tkraise()


def show_error(mes):
    messagebox.showerror(title=None, message=mes)


def login_btn_func():
    l_username = login_page_username.get()
    l_password = login_page_password.get()
    username_password_found = False
    with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
        csv_reader = DictReader(f)
        for row in csv_reader:
            if row['username'] == l_username and row['password'] == l_password:
                username_password_found = True
    if username_password_found:
        show_page(logged_in_page)
    else:
        show_error('Incorrect username or password.')


def signup_btn_func():
    s_username = signup_page_username.get()
    s_password = signup_page_password.get()
    s_username_found = False
    with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
        csv_reader = DictReader(f)
        for row in csv_reader:
            if row['username'] == s_username:
                s_username_found = True
    if s_username_found:
        show_error('Username already taken. Try different!')
    else:
        with open('data.csv', 'a', newline='\n') as f:
            csv_writer = DictWriter(f, fieldnames=['username', 'password'])
            csv_writer.writerow({
                'username': s_username,
                'password': s_password
            })
        show_page(logged_in_page)


main_page = tk.Frame(win)
login_page = tk.Frame(win)
signup_page = tk.Frame(win)
logged_in_page = tk.Frame(win)

for frame in (main_page, login_page, signup_page, logged_in_page):
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

show_page(main_page)


# CODE FOR MAIN PAGE
main_page_login_btn = tk.Button(main_page, text='Login', width=10, font="verdana", command=lambda: show_page(login_page))
main_page_login_btn.place(x=40, y=80)

main_page_signup_btn = tk.Button(main_page, text='SignUp', width=10, font='verdana', command=lambda: show_page(signup_page))
main_page_signup_btn.place(x=160, y=80)


# CODE FOR LOGIN PAGE
# creating labels
login_page_username_label = tk.Label(login_page, text='Username', font='verdana')
login_page_username_label.place(x=30, y=40)

login_page_password_label = tk.Label(login_page, text='Password', font='verdana')
login_page_password_label.place(x=30, y=80)
# creating entries
login_page_username = tk.StringVar()
login_page_username_entry = tk.Entry(login_page, font='verdana', textvariable=login_page_username)
login_page_username_entry.place(x=120, y=40, width=150, height=25)

login_page_password = tk.StringVar()
login_page_password_entry = tk.Entry(login_page, font='verdana', show='*', textvariable=login_page_password)
login_page_password_entry.place(x=120, y=80, width=150, height=25)
# creating button
login_page_login_btn = tk.Button(login_page, text='Login', font='verdana', command=login_btn_func)
login_page_login_btn.place(x=120, y=120)

login_page_signup_btn = tk.Button(login_page, text='Create Account', font='verdana', command=lambda: show_page(signup_page))
login_page_signup_btn.place(x=155, y=160)

# CODE FOR SIGNUP PAGE
# creating labels
signup_page_username_label = tk.Label(signup_page, text='Username', font='verdana')
signup_page_username_label.place(x=30, y=40)

signup_page_password_label = tk.Label(signup_page, text='Password', font='verdana')
signup_page_password_label.place(x=30, y=80)
# creating entries
signup_page_username = tk.StringVar()
signup_page_username_entry = tk.Entry(signup_page, font='verdana', textvariable=signup_page_username)
signup_page_username_entry.place(x=120, y=40, width=150, height=25)

signup_page_password = tk.StringVar()
signup_page_password_entry = tk.Entry(signup_page, font='verdana', show='*', textvariable=signup_page_password)
signup_page_password_entry.place(x=120, y=80, width=150, height=25)
# creating button
signup_page_signup_btn = tk.Button(signup_page, text='SignUp', font='verdana', command=signup_btn_func)
signup_page_signup_btn.place(x=120, y=120)

signup_page_login_btn = tk.Button(signup_page, text='Login', font='verdana', command=lambda: show_page(login_page))
signup_page_login_btn.place(x=210, y=165)
# creating footer label
signup_page_footer_label = tk.Label(signup_page, text='Already have an account? ', font=('verdana', 10))
signup_page_footer_label.place(x=25, y=170)

# CODE FOR LOGGED IN PAGE
logged_in_page_welcome_message = tk.Label(logged_in_page, text='Welcome Back! Logged in to your account.', font=('verdana', 9))
logged_in_page_welcome_message.pack()

# logged in page button
logged_in_page_logout_btn = tk.Button(logged_in_page, text='Logout', font='verdana', command=lambda: show_page(login_page))
logged_in_page_logout_btn.place(x=223, y=160)


win.mainloop()
```